# Run image transition and animation simultaneously with some precision?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am building a website as part of some university coursework and my landing page design is fairly ambitious, designed to wow my professor.

It requires many images of different types, jpegs, pngs and animated gifs which all appear to have a negative impact on loading time and gracefulness.

So what I'm building is a little stage-themed image carousel, what I'm trying to make it do is:

```
Roll curtain up revealing first image   
Roll curtain down & change to second image
Roll curtain up revealing second image 
Roll curtain down & change to third image
Roll curtain up revealing third image
and so on.. looping through the images indefinitely
```

Whilst this is going on there is a simple animated spotlight gif overlaying the image carousel, running constantly.

I am aware that there are a number of ways to achieve this, I'm trying to find the most smooth and precise method. What I have managed to constuct so far is a basic image carousel that isn't very wow, and a curtain that rolls up first time only on most browsers (it only rolls up and down constantly on Dreamweaver CS5).

I am asking here because I have tried a number of different ways and have been searching the web for 3 days trying to find a relevant example to work from. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You can view a working example **[here](http://www.domscodestage.com/LPAC%20site/)**

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var imgs = ['images/logopic.png','images/lobby.png','images/worksofshake.jpg','images/worksofshake.jpg'];
var cnt = imgs.length;
setInterval(Slider, 6000);

function Slider() {
    $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn("slow");
    });
$("#curtaindown").animate({height:"95%"});
    /*$("#curtaindown").animate({height:"75%"});
    $("#curtaindown").animate({height:"50%"});
    $("#curtaindown").animate({height:"30%"});*/
    $("#curtaindown").animate({height:"5%"},5000);
    $("#curtaindown").animate({height:"95%"},5000);
    $(".leadinfo").hide();
    }
});
```

Thank-you for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually settled on a very simple implementation that works even though I'm fairly sure it logically shouldn't. If someone could comment to explain why it does work I'd be very grateful.

This is the code I eventually used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#scroller_container_top").hide();

    var imgs = ['images/logopic.png','images/lobbywithcaption.jpg','images/seatswithcaption.jpg','images/worksofshake.jpg'];
var cnt = imgs.length;
setInterval(Slider, 10000);

function Slider() {
    $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn("slow");

    });

    $("#curtaindown").animate({height:"5%"},5000);
    $("#curtaindown").animate({height:"95%"},5000);     

};

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution assumes that on page load, the curtain is covering up the image and the first image is already set on #imageSlide.  I haven't tested it, but the general idea should be correct.  One problem with this solution is that with a bad internet connection, there's a chance the curtain will pull away before the image is actually done downloading.  Accounting for that is a bit messier, so I didn't get into it.

```
var imgs = [...];
var nextImage = 1;
var $image = $('#imageSlide');
var $curtain = $('#curtaindown');

hideCurtain();
preloadNextImage();
// Show the next image in 6 seconds
setTimeout(showNextImage, 6000);

function showNextImage() {
  showCurtain(function(){       
    // Set the img tag to the new image
    $image.attr('src', imgs[nextImage]);

    nextImage++;
    if (nextImage.length >= imgs.length)
      nextImage = 0;
    preloadNextImage();

    // After the curtain is hidden, wait 5 more seconds before
    // switching to the next one.
    hideCurtain(function(){
        setTimeout(showNextImage, 5000);
    });
  });
}

function showCurtain(onComplete) {
  $curtain.animate({height:'95%'},
      { duration: 500,
        complete: onComplete });
}

function hideCurtain(onComplete) {
  $curtain.animate({height:'5%'},
      { duration: 500,
        complete: onComplete });
}

function preloadNextImage() {
  // Start downloading the next image.
  (new Image()).src = imgs[nextImage];
}
```

Comment: It looks promising, but at the moment it's not working, the curtain is just staying down. I had to change both $curtain.animate({'height,'95%'}, to $curtain.animate({height:"95%"}, as Dreamweaver was throwing a syntax error. Do I need to change the value on var $image?

Comment: Dominic, if you are not familiar with them, learn the Chrome Developer Tools.  This will let you walk through the code and see which lines are getting called, which ones are failing to run, and what the values of variables are at any given time.  In the Console, you can see if any errors are being thrown.  http://goo.gl/4NMEA